# (HTML/Js) Cycling element visibilities

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, visibility

```js
var terminal = document.getElementById('terminal');
var vncScreen = document.getElementById('screen');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

var vncToggle = document.getElementById('vncToggle');
var termToggle = document.getElementById('terminalToggle');

termToggle.onclick = function toggleTerminal() {

  if (terminal.classList.contains('hide')) {
    terminal.classList.remove('hide'); 
    if (vncScreen.classList.contains('hide')) {} else {vncScreen.classList.add('hide')}
    if (video.classList.contains('hide')) {} else {video.classList.add('hide')}
  } else {
    terminal.classList.add('hide'); 
    if (video.classList.contains('hide')) {video.classList.remove('hide')} else {}
  }
}

vncToggle.onclick = function toggleVNC() {

  if (vncScreen.classList.contains('hide')) {
    vncScreen.classList.remove('hide'); 
    if (terminal.classList.contains('hide')) {} else {terminal.classList.add('hide')}
    if (video.classList.contains('hide')) {} else {video.classList.add('hide')}
  } else {
    vncScreen.classList.add('hide'); 
    if (video.classList.contains('hide')) {video.classList.remove('hide')} else {}
 }
}
```

```css
.black-box {
  background: black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}

.green-box {
  background: green;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}

.blue-box {
  background: blue;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="terminalToggle" title="Toggle Terminal">Toggle terminal</button>
<button class="button" id="vncToggle" title="Toggle Terminal">Toggle vnc</button>

<div id='video' class="black-box"></div>
<div id='screen' class="green-box hide"></div>
<div id='terminal' class="blue-box hide"></div>
```

*basically when you click "Toggle terminal" it should show blue and then if you click again go back to black; when you click "Toggle vnc" it should show green and then if you click again go back to black. If you click "Toggle vnc" and it is already blue, it should turn green and vice versa (but clicking "Toggle terminal")*

I currently have the following `Js`:

```
      var terminal = document.getElementById('terminal');          //video-like element
      var vncScreen = document.getElementById('screen');           //video-like element
      var video = document.getElementById('video');                //video-like element

      var vncToggle = document.getElementById('vncToggle');        //button
      var termToggle = document.getElementById('terminalToggle');  //button

      termToggle.onclick = function toggleTerminal() {
        terminal.classList.toggle('hide');
        vncScreen.classList.toggle('hide');
        video.classList.toggle('hide');
      }
      vncToggle.onclick = function toggleVNC() {
        vncScreen.classList.toggle('hide');
        terminal.classList.toggle('hide');
        video.classList.toggle('hide');
      }
```

and `css`:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

When I had just two different HTML elements, this class toggling methodology worked. Now that there are 3, I'm not sure it will work as desired.

`video` is initially visible i.e. `hide` is not in its `classList`

`terminal` is initially hidden i.e. `hide` is in its `classList`

`vncScreen` is initially hidden i.e. `hide` is in its `classList`

When `toggleTerminal()` is called:

- `video` becomes hidden
- `terminal` becomes visible
- `vncScreen` becomes visible (*but it should not*)

If `toggleVNC()` is called (after `toggleTerminal()`):

- `video` becomes visible again (*but it should not*)
- `terminal` becomes hidden
- `vncScreen` becomes hidden

Note how if the either of the function calls were toggled only by themselves, this method would work (provided I removed `vncScreen.classList.toggle('hide');` in `toggleTerminal()` and `terminal.classList.toggle('hide');` in `toggleVNC()`).

The problem is I need to account for any order of button-presses of `termToggle` and `vncToggle`. Essentially my goal is to "cycle" these elements such that:

1) Toggling of the "selected" element (i.e. `termToggle` corresponds to visibility of `terminal` element && `vncToggle` corresponds to visibility of `vncScreen` element) hides the remaining two elements (`video` && `vncScreen` || `terminal` && `video` respectively)

2) The order of toggling of "selected" elements does not affect 1)

3) A second toggle of the "selected" element will hide itself and the other element that is not `video`

Any ideas on how to best accomplish this?

At one point I thought about doing some logic that evaluated whether `hide` was contained in the appropriate `classList`'s and just manually add or remove the `hide` class accordingly but this seemed kind of sloppy to me (idk, maybe its not?).

Comment: Did you know that the attribute `hidden` does the same as the class `hide`, but without needing any CSS?

Comment: May you put a stack snippet in the question showing the issue?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I did not know that - so it would be used like `object.style.visibility = "visible|hidden|collapse|initial|inherit"` or what you are talking about is something different?

Comment: @evolutionxbox good idea, i will work on one

Comment: `setAttribute('hidden','')` and `removeAttribute('hidden')`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I created a snippet - basically when you click "Toggle terminal" it should show blue and then if you click again go back to black; when you click "Toggle vnc" it should show green and then if you click again go back to black. If you click "Toggle vnc" and it is already blue, it should turn green and vice versa (but clicking "Toggle terminal")

Comment: I would avoid using `toggle` as it doesn't do what you want. Instead remove the class instead using `classList.remove('hide')`

Comment: @evolutionxbox this is tough... I'm closer in my snippet but dang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code snippet in question for functionality, `Js` redundantly posted here:

```
var terminal = document.getElementById('terminal');
var vncScreen = document.getElementById('screen');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

var vncToggle = document.getElementById('vncToggle');
var termToggle = document.getElementById('terminalToggle');

termToggle.onclick = function toggleTerminal() {

  if (terminal.classList.contains('hide')) {
    terminal.classList.remove('hide'); 
    if (vncScreen.classList.contains('hide')) {} else {vncScreen.classList.add('hide')}
    if (video.classList.contains('hide')) {} else {video.classList.add('hide')}
  } else {
    terminal.classList.add('hide'); 
    if (video.classList.contains('hide')) {video.classList.remove('hide')} else {}
  }
}

vncToggle.onclick = function toggleVNC() {

  if (vncScreen.classList.contains('hide')) {
    vncScreen.classList.remove('hide'); 
    if (terminal.classList.contains('hide')) {} else {terminal.classList.add('hide')}
    if (video.classList.contains('hide')) {} else {video.classList.add('hide')}
  } else {
    vncScreen.classList.add('hide'); 
    if (video.classList.contains('hide')) {video.classList.remove('hide')} else {}
    }
}
```